# VBA - If a cell in column A is not blank the column B equals

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for some code that will look at Column A and as long as the cell in Column A is not blank, then the corresponding cell in Column B will equal a specific value.

So if Cell A1 <> "" then Cell B1.Value = "MyText"
And repeat until a cell in Column A is blank or empty.

To add a little more clarification, I have looked through the various loop questions asked and answered here.  They were somewhat helpful.  However, I'm unclear on how to get the loop to go through Column A to verify that each cell in Column A isn't blank AND in the corresponding cell in Column B, add some text that I specify.

Also, this will need to be part of a VBA macro and not part of a cell formula such as =IF

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Looping until the next blank cell has been asked several times on this site...

Comment: Why not just enter your formula and autofill?

Comment: @DavidZemens: + 1 You have hit the nail on the head ;) Since the user wants a VBA solution what you have suggested can be ported to VBA as well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want a vba solution you can loop through a range like this:

```
Sub Check()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    dat = rng
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
            rng(i, 2).Value = "My Text"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT********

Instead of using varients you can just loop through the range like this:

```
Sub Check()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Set the range in column A you want to loop through
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'write to adjacent cell
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "My Text"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of interest why have the range as an array? Why not simply loop through the cells in the range `( e.g. for each cl in rng)` and use `Offset` to populate column B `(e.g. If cl <> "" Then cl.Offset(0,1) = "My Text")`

Comment: I certainly could, I cut some code that was already written.  I believe looping through a variant is faster then a range but may be wrong on this.  I'll edit it to make is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Another way (Using Formulas in VBA). I guess this is the shortest VBA code as well?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Formula = "=If(A1<>"""",""My Text"","""")"
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Value = .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do this would be:

```
Sub populateB()

For Each Cel in Range("A1:A100")
    If Cel.value <> "" Then Cel.Offset(0, 1).value = "Your Text"
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function IF :

`=IF ( logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false )`