# Replacing Special Characters in Excel VBA and adding columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new to Excel VBA Macros, as my job demanded something challenging. To give you all a brief intro, I receive a file on a daily basis where I have to find all special characters ( **@ * ( ) _ + [ ] \ : ; “ ‘ , . / ?** ) from column A. Add three columns C, D and E which should auto-fill values viz - Column C should fill in "XYZ", Column D to have "ABC" and Column E to have "NA". The same values should be copied in the new columns that get added till the last data row.

I did create something, which works for removing special characters, except the double quotes ("). Also, I did not find a way to have the file saved as an EXE, that when clicked finds the Excel Workbook open with its name and executes this function.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this code. I'm really naive with VBA programming. If this works out, would be a big help for my day to day work management!

Appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Akshay

```
 Sub Remove_Special()
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=";", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=":", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=",", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="(", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=")", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="{", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="}", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="[", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="]", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="~+", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="~*", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="~?", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="_", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=".", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="'", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="\", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="/", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=".", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:="@", Replacement:=""
Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=Chr(34), Replacement:=""

MsgBox "All special characters have been removed", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here for something similar:
[VBA - If a cell in column A is not blank the column B equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368277/vba-if-a-cell-in-column-a-is-not-blank-the-column-b-equals)

Also try this for removing the double quotes:

```
myVariable = Replace(myVariable, Chr(34), "")
```

You could just copy and paste the workbook's contents to the macro-enabled workbook instead of creating an executable file.

Comment: Now, I'm trying to work on two things. I was able to create a code similar to my requirements and that worked partially. Thanks!

Comment: Now, I am trying to Concatenate values from two columns, but with the following code, the concatenated columns adds a "-" till the last cell in the Excel sheet. Any advise, would be really appreciated.

Dim lngLastRow As Long
 lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
 Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=G2:G" & lngLastRow & "&""-""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)