# If a cell in column A is not blank then column B equals and column C equals

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to fill several columns with data if the cell in column B is blank
I have managed to do this for one column but am struggling to get it to run for more than one column…
So if B is not blank, then complete column K with Customer, complete column P with Allow and complete column Q with Normal (haven’t done as haven’t got P to work yet!)

```
For Each Cel In Range("B18:B90000")
    If Cel.Value <> "" _
    Then Cel.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Customer"
    'Cel.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Allow"
Next
```

This helped me to do it for one column:
[VBA - If a cell in column A is not blank the column B equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368277/vba-if-a-cell-in-column-a-is-not-blank-the-column-b-equals)
This helped me to perform 2 actions but its not working
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524212-vba-if-statements-can-you-have-multiple-actions-then-area.html
If anyone can help, it would be massively appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just forgot `End If` and the Offset stay fixed on B, so the values is not 5 but 14 :

```
For Each Cel In Range("B18:B90000")
    If Cel.Value <> "" Then
        Cel.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Customer"
        Cel.Offset(0, 14).Value = "Allow"
        Cel.Offset(0, 15).Value = "Normal"
    End If
Next
```

I prefer to put Then inline with the If, as vba does read it that way (if you use f8 in the vba console, you'll see).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub FillIn()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 18 To 90000
        If Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
            Cells(i, "K") = "Customer"
            Cells(i, "P") = "Allow"
            Cells(i, "Q") = "Normal"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you also... not sure which of the 2 answers would run the quickest but its good to see the different ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use the following which should be quicker

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B18:B90000")
        Dim Cel As Range
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then
            For Each Cel In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                Cel.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Customer"
                Cel.Offset(0, 14).Value = "Allow"
                Cel.Offset(0, 15).Value = "Normal"
             Next Cel
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```